# Why is the following variable assignment not working correctly?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, c++14

I tried to convert users input from string to `int` by casting each character to `int` and multiply by its corresponding exponential. Everything works correctly till the point I need to assign the result value to a `int` variable. It always one less than the correct value when the assigned value is between 100 and 1000.
i.e. `int k=0; k+=100;` But printing k shows 99. But `k+=1000` works fine.

The solution I found is to change the order of multiplicand and multiplier, but the cause to this situation is still unknown.

```
string k_input;
cin >> k_input;
int k = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < k_input.length(); i++)
{
    cout << (k_input[i] - '0') << " " << pow(10, (k_input.length() - i) - 1) << endl;

    k += (k_input[i] - '0') * pow(10, k_input.length() - i - 1);
}
```

i.e. By inputting 123, output should be 123, but it shows 122 instead.

And inputting 1221 shows 1221 as expected.

Comment: You know there are better ways to convert strings to integers in c++, right? Btw, your code seems to work.

Comment: I know, it's not my code. I'm asking for my roommate. And this problem makes me kinda curious.

Comment: I've just tried your code and it works as expected with `123`: https://onlinegdb.com/Sk-BRGz9B

Comment: "I know, it's not my code. I'm asking for my roommate." So who's code doesn't work? Because the code you posted works.

Comment: wow, I may found the cause to the problem. I tried the code on two different computer (both vscode), and getting the same error. But running it on online compiler works correctly. So maybe there's some environment setting that's wrong?

Comment: Which compiler do you use?

Comment: gcc version 8.2.0 (MinGW.org GCC-8.2.0-3), and compile with (g++ .\test.cpp -std=c++14)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem, which may very well be compiler- and/or platform-specific, is almost certainly down to 'rounding' errors when converting the `double` output of your calculation to an `int` value. You can fix this by using the `lround` function (defined in `<cmath>`):

```cpp
k += lround((k_input[i] - '0') * pow(10, k_input.length() - i - 1));
```

Incidentally, turning on **compiler warnings** will highlight issues like this! For your code, in Visual Studio, I was shown:

```
warning C4244: '+=': conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data
```

Comment: That works, but why changing the order of multiplicand and multiplier will fix the issue? Maybe it's like what you said, compiler bug?

Comment: There's no 'order changing' in the code I posted! And its not a 'bug' - it's a feature: the binary **floating point** representation of the number `3` may actually be `2.999999`, which will convert to an `int` as `2`. The [lround](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round) function finds the ***nearest*** integer, which is what you want.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, I mean I tried to switch the order, and the problem fixed. Thank you for the fine explanation. Will definitely try the lround function.